# Sound on Windows mutes itself for a few seconds after volume adjusment

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, troubleshooting

I'm using Windows 10 (19042) and when I adjust the volume (inc or dec) the sound almost completely mutes itself and it comes back to a set value after a new seconds.
If I then adjust the volume further, it doesn't mute. But after a few minutes the problems comes back and any new adjustment causes temporary mute.

It affects Spotify and browsers (Chrome, Firefox) - so I assume Windows sound in general.

I already tried "Control panel -> Sound -> Communication -> Do nothing when detecting communication" - but it didn't solve it.

Comment: Did you try updating the Audio Driver?

Comment: It says the driver is already the newest version.